# how to add time from string with %Y%m%d%H%M%S format

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

look at my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
aaa=20200101101010
bbb=$(date -d "$aaa -5 minutes" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

echo $bbb
```

i want to get:

```
20200101100510
```

but result is:

```
20200101101009235500
```

what happend?

How can I subtract 5 minutes from that aaa?

I want to see 20200101100510

Comment: My answer to your older question shows what happened.

Comment: Hi muru, thanks for the previous answer. But I don't know what to do in the above situation. Should I replace aaa with ISO-8601?

Comment: @muru please tell me how to parse that format as ISO-8601

Comment: @ohmg.  Rather than answer your Q, might I kindly suggest you think about HOW to break down the problem into smaller pieces.  For example, first you can try this on the command line without the bbb=$(.  Furthermore you can use echo to see what the parameter strings look like.  Teaching you how to help yourself will be of more value to you than showing you the answer to any one problem I think.

Comment: If you can't change the input, you'll have to split it up: something like `date -d "${aaa:0:4}-${aaa:4:2}-${aaa:6:2} ${aaa:8:2}:${aaa:10:2}:${aaa:12:2} +0 - 5 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

Comment: I have tried many things. But nothing works.

Comment: @muru Thank you again. But this still doesn't work `20200101190510`. I will apply your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the GNU implementation of `date` where that `20200101101010` is interpreted as `2020010110-10-10T00:00:00` local time.

`-d` is a non-standard option of `date`, supported by only a handful of implementations and on those where it's supported, if it is to input a date at all (like in GNU, busybox or ast-open's `date`; BSD `date` using `-r` and `-v` instead), it's done differently in different implementations.

`ast-open` and busybox `date` allow to specify the input format (busybox with `-D`, ast-open with `-p`) though not with an offset AFAIK. You could however remove the 5 minutes by converting first to epochtime, remove the 300 seconds and convert back to your format.

[There was a proposal in July 2019 to add something similar to GNU `date`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2019-07/msg00053.html) but it's not been released yet (as of 2020-01-21).

With GNU `date` specifically, you could convert the input (`$aaa`) first into a format it recognizes like in [@RakeshShewale's `ksh93` syntax approach](/a/563142).

Another option is to use the `zsh` shell which has the timestamp parsing and formatting feature built-in and avoid having to rely on non-portable behaviour of `date`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime || exit
format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S min=60

aaa=20200101101010

strftime -r -s bbb -- "$format" "$aaa" || exit
strftime    -s bbb -- "$format" "$((bbb - 5 * min))"
print -r -- "$bbb"
```

You can adapt the `$format` as required for other formats but note that not all format directives supported by `strftime()` (called by `strftime` without `-r` to *format* timestamps) are supported by `strptime()` (called by `strftime -r` to *parse* timestamps). Check `man 3 strftime` and `man 3 strptime` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=20200101101010
bbb=$(date --date "${a:0:4}-${a:4:2}-${a:6:2} ${a:8:2}:${a:10:2}:${a:12:2}")
ccc=$(date -d "$bbb -5 mins" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
echo $ccc
```

output:

```
20200101100510
```

Comment: That's ksh93 syntax though (also supported by bash/mksh/zsh/busybox ash), not sh syntax though.

Comment: Also using the default output format for `$bbb` is a bad idea as the timezone specification is ambiguous and it won't work properly in non-US-English locales. You should use a ISO-8601 type of format instead.